# conda install slow on Kubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda, conda

I've recently noticed that conda seems sluggish on my machine. It takes about an hour to install packages, and reinstalling anaconda took ~5 hours. It gets there eventually, but it hangs for a long time after it's finished printing the package names and #s. I don't remember it being so slow before, but it's hard to say.

It's connected to the building network (apparently other machines on the network aren't so slow with conda) and I'm wondering whether it's the operating system or if there's anything else that could be slowing it down? I'm quite new to linux and haven't been able to find anything so far about this.

I've got Kubuntu 16.04

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: What command did you use to reinstall anaconda? Did you download the installer and execute it?

Comment: I downloaded Anaconda2-4.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh and then I ran it with 'bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda2-4.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh' (following the instructions on the website). I agreed yes to everything and then added the default path to my bashrc file

Comment: And running `bash ~/Downloads...` took 5 hours? If not, what's the part that took 5 hours? That seems unreasonable :-)

Comment: Yep it's that which took 5 hours :/ I'm trying to update scipy now, and the estimated time is 2:49:26 with a speed of 3.78 kB/s - I'm not really sure what is being so slow, is it the connection to the internet?

Comment: It seems like its the internet connection... can you visit speedtest.net and see how fast your connection is?

Comment: That would make sense as the speed can change quite a lot (?) - it got up to 100 kB/s at one point. I'm getting a download speed of 21.47Mbps on  speedtest.net